# LuaLaTeX bugged out with unicode in supplementary planes?

Tags: luatex, unicode, bugs

MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=0pt, 12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{FiraCodeNerdFontPropo}[
  Extension = .ttf,
  Path = ../../../fonts/FiraCodeNerdFont/,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold
]

\begin{document}
  \texttt{^^^^^^0f0072}
\end{document}
```

I used the font here: https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads

Based on the font cheat sheet (https://www.nerdfonts.com/cheat-sheet), 0x0f0072 is a barcode icon.

The above code, when compiled with XeLaTeX, indeed gives a barcode icon.

However, when compiled with LuaLaTeX, the PDF shows a bank icon (which is 0x0f0070).

After some test I found that LuaLaTeX seems to shift every icon by 0x2.

I don't know if I missed something or this is just a bug.

Comment: I don't know how to do that in (Lua)latex, but I would try to access the glyphs via name I stead of number..

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately LaTeX doesn't have a material design icon package yet afaik...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with supplementary planes but specifically with the private use planes. LuaLaTeX's default `node` mode does not expect private use codepoints to be input directly and therefore freely remaps them.

If you don't want this, you can use `harf` mode instead, e.g. with `fontspec`'s `Renderer = HarfBuzz` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmonofont{FiraCodeNerdFontPropo}[
  Extension = .ttf,
  Path = ../../../fonts/FiraCodeNerdFont/,
  UprightFont = *-Regular,
  BoldFont = *-Bold,
  Renderer = HarfBuzz
]

\begin{document}
  \texttt{^^^^^^0f0072}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. `harf` as you provided indeed works when compiling to PDF, but does not seem to work on `dvilualatex` with `dvisvgm` when compiling to SVG (`ERROR: can't load glyph 983154`). Do you know why?